# read arrays from a JSON file to your GO variables

Tags: arrays, json, go

I have been tasked with converting my project from Python to Go, but I've been stumped for hours on this.

I have this file data.json which contains the following data

```
{
    "mobiles":["iPhone 13 Pro","OnePlus 10 Pro","Google Pixel 6"], 
    "laptops":["Dell XSP 13","Acer Chromebook Spin","Lenovo ThinkPad x1"], 
    "cars":["Suzuki Crossover","Golf GTI","Hyundai Tucson","Hyundai Kona"]
}
```

For my project, I would like to load the data from data.json into the following slices

```
mobiles := []{ data from json }
laptops := []{ data from json }
cars := []{ data from json }
```

I'm thinking of using slices, if I'm not wrong would that allow me to add more data to my arrays in the json file as I need?

```
    jsonFile, err := os.Open("data/data.json")  
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(jsonFile)
    fmt.Println("Successfully Opened data.json")
```

This gives me:
&{0xc000062180}
Successfully Opened data.json

I was trying to target the data I need with for example:

```
fmt.Println(jsonFile["cars"])
```

Do I need to learn about pointers or am I completly barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: do I need a struct something like this?                                                                     
     ```type data struct {
 cars    []string `json:"cars"`
 laptops []string `json:"laptops"`
 mobiles []string `json:"mobiles"`
} ```

Comment: The application must unmarshal the file data to Go values.  See [json.Unmarshal](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

type Todo struct {
    Mobiles []string `json:"mobiles"`
    Laptops  []string `json:"laptops"`
    Cars  []string `json:"cars"`
}

func main() {
    jsonFile, err := os.Open("file.json")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    
    defer jsonFile.Close()

    byteValue, err := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var todo Todo
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(byteValue), &todo)

    fmt.Println(todo)
    fmt.Println(todo.Cars)
}
```

the first output will be your json file

> {[iPhone 13 Pro OnePlus 10 Pro Google Pixel 6] [Dell XSP 13 Acer
> Chromebook Spin Lenovo ThinkPad x1] [Suzuki Crossover Golf GTI Hyundai
> Tucson Hyundai Kona]}

and the second the cars

> [Suzuki Crossover Golf GTI Hyundai Tucson Hyundai Kona]